# Scale SVG with mouse wheel in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I am working currently with SNAP.SVG in JS and I want to scale a SVG-Path on mouswheel movement. It would be nice if somebody could help me with it.

paper.path(pathString).attr({
         fill: "#EFA3A0",
         stroke: "#FFFFF5",
         strokeWidth: 0.2,
       });

Thank you!

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: You can scale with el.transform('s1,2') or 's3' to scale 1,2 on the x,y plane or scale 3 in both. Just attach some multiplier to your mousewheel movement and create that string from it. 's' + mwheelfactor  for example.